# pycharm evaluate expression result search

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

[image]

How can I search in the Result pane of the evaluate expression window?
I need some sort of CTRL+F ability to search with a string among the result object.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's not possible yet. Vote/comment for the respective feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20692 .